# Using html forms and php for validation on blank textarea or if default value is present

Tags: php, html, validation, forms, default-value

Hi I have a form I am trying to validate the textarea at the bottom. I want it so if the default value is present or if the box is empty it errors. This is the part of my form i am looking at:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="email.php">    

<p><label style="width: 400px; float: left; height: 20px" for="comments">Your enquiry details?</label>
<textarea style="width: 400px; height: 84px" id="comments" rows="1" cols="1" 
          onfocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue) { this.value = ''; }" 
          name="comments">
e.g. There are 5 of us looking to hire either caravan for 7 nights on the dates above. Are we able to have BBQ's?
</textarea> </p>

 All sections MUST be completed!<br />

<p class="submit">    
<button type="reset">Reset</button>    
<button name="send" type="submit">Submit</button> </p></fieldset> </form>
```

This is part of my PHP page:

```
$string_exp = ".";
 if(!eregi($string_exp,$comments)) {
    $error_message .= 'You did not leave a comment!.<br />';
```

This works correctly by erroring if the textarea is blank (as I have the regular expression "." so they can use any thing on the keyboard for their comments) but I also want it to error if it still says the default value of "e.g. There are 5 of us looking to hire either caravan for 7 nights on the dates above. Are we able to have BBQ's?"

How can I do this?

Kind regards

Comment: Seriously? Using a regex to check if a string is empty? Simply test `if(!$comments)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!$comments || $comments == 'There are 5 of us looking to hire either caravan for 7 nights on the dates above. Are we able to have BBQ's?')
```

If it's ok to have the text only in non-IE browsers you could also use the HTML5 placeholder attribute ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/rN3vk/)):

```
<textarea ... placeholder="here are 5 of us looking to hire either caravan for 7 nights on the dates above. Are we able to have BBQ's?"></textarea>
```

Comment: Great thanks Zirak! that worked for me and I will look in to preg_match.

Comment: Actually this worked on my test server but when I put it on the live server it didn't for some reason, same code and everything. So I used ThiefMaster's instead and like the placeholder part too :)

Answer (score 1):

Expand your check to include your current check, and also a string check.

```
$default = "e.g. There are 5 of us looking to hire either caravan for 7 nights on the dates above. Are we able to have BBQ's?"

if (($comments == "") || ($comments == $default))) {
   $error_message .= 'You did not leave a comment!.<br />';
```

For bonus points, use the `$default` variable to populate your template, so you don't have it written in two places.

Answer (score 1):

First, [the eregi function](http://php.net/eregi) is deprecated since php 5.3. [preg_match](http://php.net/preg_match) is the way to go!

Second, if you want to test if *no* value was entered, why not compare to...nothing? php will treat empty strings as falsy values.

Third, assuming you have the value, why not compare to it?

```
if (!$comments || $comments === 'my default value') {
    $error_message .= 'You did not leave a comment!.<br />';
}
```

Take a look at php's documentation on [Boolean values](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding.
But if you want to validate on the server side (email.php) you can just do:

```
$default_comment = "There are 5 of us looking to hire either caravan for 7 nights on the dates above. Are we able to have BBQ's?"

$comments = (string)$_POST['comments'];

if( empty($comments) || $comments == $default_comment )
    $error_message .= 'You did not leave a comment!.<br />';
```